# Why can I have a std::vector<std::ofstream*> but not a std::vector<std::ofstream>?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, ofstream

I have the following test code in which I have a parameter `fS` which is a container of `ofstream`s:

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstdio>

    int main()
    {
        // my container of ofstream(s)
        std::vector<std::ofstream> fS;

        // instantiate an ofstream
        std::ofstream of("myfile.txt");

        // push back to my container
        fS.push_back(of);

        return 0;
    }
```

This does not compile at all. Whereas when I change the container of `ofstream` into a container of pointers to `ofstream`s, the code compiles:

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstdio>

    int main()
    {
        // my container of ofstream(s)
        std::vector<std::ofstream*> fS;

        // instantiate an ofstream
        std::ofstream * of = new std::ofstream("myfile.txt");

        // push back to my container
        fS.push_back(of);

        return 0;
    }
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `push_back(of)` on a `vector`, it tries to add a copy of the object `of` to the vector. (C++ loves making copies of things). In this case, you're trying to copy an `ofstream`, which isn't permitted. Intuitively, it's not clear what it would mean to have a copy of an `ofstream`, so the spec prohibits it.

On the other hand, suppose you have a `vector` of `ofstream*`s. Now, if you try to `push_back` a pointer to an `ofstream`, then C++ interprets this to mean that you should put a copy of the *pointer* into the `vector`, and that's okay because pointers can easily be copied around.

There's a third option, though, if you have a recent compiler. C++ recently introduced the idea of *move semantics*, that instead of trying to *copy* the file stream into the vector, you can *move* the file stream into the vector. You could therefore write something like this:

```
int main()
{
    // my container of ofstream(s)
    std::vector<std::ofstream> fS;

    // instantiate an ofstream
    std::ofstream of("myfile.txt");

    // push back to my container
    fS.push_back(std::move(of));

    return 0;
}
```

After doing this, the variable `of` won't refer to the original file stream anymore; it'll instead just have some dummy value. However, the vector will now effectively contain the stream that used to be stored in `of`.

Comment: you could always `emplace_back` as well, constructing the `ofstream` in place in the `vector`.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I have not realized C++ loved copies... interesting.

Comment: `fS.emplace_back("myfile.txt");`

Comment: And you also get strong exception guarantee for free, @M.M .